# What are good tutorials for Ubuntu network configuration from command line?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, command-line, documentation

I had been using Ubuntu for some time, but no really comfortable with the Ubuntu networking concepts from command line. I searched on the internet, but could not find any nice tutorials for configuring the network from the command line. Any pointers?

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu is Debian based so documentation for Debian may be useful.

I would also recommend the book "Ubuntu Linux Toolbox" by Cristopher Negus and Francois Caen. It is basically a book of command line recipes for Ubuntu and includes a chapter about network setup.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu by default uses the NetworkManager software for network configuration, which is designed to be used from a GUI. There are some command-line tools for it (nmcli, cnetworkmanager), but their functionality is very limited compared to the GUI.

Debian (and Ubuntu) have a very basic network configuration system, separate from NetworkManager, in the form of `/etc/network/iterfaces` and the `ifup` and `ifdown` commands. However, this is not much more than shortcuts to a few commands (like `ifconfig` and `route`). They do not appear to have advanced features like dependencies and event-driven configuration. For example, they cannot handle the network cable being pulled in or out, to deconfigure the interface when the cable is out. The `/etc/network/interfaces` system is documented by Debian, see http://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration .

There is some software (e.g. ifplugd) that will solve this by monitoring the state of network interface and invoking the `ifup` or `ifdown` commands when interface state changes. However, this is still limited to responding just to the interface state, and can't be used for e.g. dependencies between interfaces (example: VPN should only start when LAN is up).

If you need more powerful configuration, I recommend that you try out this software that I'm developing, which allows you to specify your network configuration in a simple but very powerful programming language: http://code.google.com/p/badvpn/wiki/NCD

Also see a similar question: [How to configure `eth0` to retry `dhclient` when unplugged and replugged?](https://superuser.com/questions/332968/how-to-configure-eth0-to-retry-dhclient-when-unplugged-and-replugged/332991)